# How to handle your own obsolete/incorrect questions?

Tags: discussion

This happened to me recently. I asked a question on SO based on my understanding of the problem at that time - some setting "A" was not working.

After further research on my end, it turned out that the actual problem was quite different. Setting "A" was working perfectly, but some other conditions negated its effect. A classic case of the X-Y problem.

Now the question contains potentially misleading information. It may not even be specific enough to document a potential red herring.

How do I handle this? Editing it will completely change the question and make all the answers look incorrect.  Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could post an answer to your question explaining how setting "A" was actually working but that it was impacted by other problematic conditions.  There could be others who encounter the same situation and would benefit from your answer.  In addition, for the people who actually do have a problem with setting "A" not working, they will be able to see all the other answers.